# How is the __class__ cell value set in class methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures, python-internals, dynamic-class-creation

Looking at [the documentation of the `super` type in Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#super), it notes that `super(…)` is the same as `super(__class__, «first argument to function»)`.  To my surprise, I wrote a method that returned `__class__` – and it actually worked:

```
>>> class c:
...   def meth(self): return __class__
... 
>>> c().meth()
<class '__main__.c'>
```

Apparently, `__class__` is a free variable assigned by the closure of the function:

```
>>> c.meth.__code__.co_freevars
('__class__',)
>>> c.meth.__closure__
(<cell at 0x7f6346a91048: type object at 0x55823b17f3a8>,)
```

I'd like to know under what circumstances that free variable is associated in the closure.  I know that if I assign a function to a variable as part of creating a class it doesn't happen.

```
>>> def meth2(self): return __class__
... 
>>> meth2.__code__.co_freevars
()
```

Even if I create a new class and as part of that creation assign some attribute to `meth2`, `meth2` doesn't somehow magically gain a free variable that gets filled in.

That's unsurprising, because part of this appears to  depend on the lexical state of the compiler at the time that the code is compiled.

I'd like to confirm that the conditions necessary for `__class__` to be treated as a free variable are simply:

- A reference to `__class__` in the code block; and
- The `def` containing the `__class__` reference is lexically within a `class` declaration block.

I'd further like to understand what the conditions necessary for that variable getting filled in correctly are. It appears – at least from the Python 3.6 documentation – that something like `type.__new__(…)` is involved somehow.  I haven't been able to understand for sure how `type` comes into play and how this all interacts with metaclasses that do not ultimately call `type.__new__(…)`.

I'm particularly confused because I didn't think that at the time the namespace's `__setattr__` method was used to assign the attribute containing the method to the method function (as it exists on the ultimately-constructed class object).  I know that this namespace object exists because it was either constructed implicitly by the use of the `class` statement, or explicitly by the metaclass's `__prepare__` method – but as best I can tell, the metaclass constructs the class object that populates `__class__` *after* the function object is set as a value within the class namespace.

Comment: It's close to why is python3.x's super magic, and I got some information from that, but I don't really feel I understand what's going on after reading that.

Comment: What do you mean with "I know that if I assign a function to a variable as part of creating a class it doesn't happen."? The example after that leaves out the "as part of creating a class". Also could you clarify your question? Are you interested in knowing when the closure is assigned? How it is assigned? In the end it will be a lot of C code to go through that doesn't tell you anything more than "if you use `__class__` or `super` in a _method_ the `__class__` name will be avaiable".

Comment: Explained the parts of this puzzle that I can't find in other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [the docs for Python’s data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), [§ 3.3.3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object) – “Creating the class object” – you will find the following:

> [The] class object is the one that will be referenced by the
>   zero-argument form of `super()`. **`__class__` is an implicit closure
>   reference created by the compiler if any methods in a class body refer
>   to either `__class__` or `super`**. This allows the zero argument form
>   of `super()` to correctly identify the class being defined **based on
>   lexical scoping**, while the class or instance that was used to make
>   the current call is identified based on the first argument passed to
>   the method.

…emphasis is mine. This confirms your two putative criteria for a `__class__` closure happening: a “`__class__`” reference in the method def, which itself is defined inside a `class` statement.

But then, the next ¶ in “Creating the class object” goes on to say:

> **CPython implementation detail:** In CPython 3.6 and later, the `__class__` cell is passed to the metaclass as a `__classcell__` entry
>   in the class namespace. If present, this must be propagated up to the
>   `type.__new__` call in order for the class to be initialized
>   correctly. Failing to do so will result in a `RuntimeError` in Python
>   3.8.

… emphasis is theirs. This means that if you are employing a metaclass with a `__new__` method – in order to dictate the terms by which classes so designated are created – for example like e.g.:

```py
class Meta(type):

    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, attributes, **kwargs):
        # Or whatever:
        if '__slots__' not in attributes:
            attributes['__slots__'] = tuple()

        # Call up, creating and returning the new class:
        return super().__new__(metacls, name,
                                        bases,
                                        attributes,
                                      **kwargs)
```

… that last `super(…).__new__(…)` call is effectively calling `type.__new__(…)`. In real life, there might be some other ancestral “`__new__(…)`” methods that get called between here and there, if your metaclass inherits from other metaclasses (like, e.g. `abc.ABCMeta`). Effectively, though, inside your `Meta.__new__(…)` method, between the method entry point, the `super(…).__new__(…)` call, and `return`-ing the new class object, you can inspect or set the value of the eventual `__class__` cell variable through `attributes['__classcell__']`†.

Now as for whether this is at all useful: I don’t know. I have been programming in [python](/questions/tagged/python) for ten years; I totally use metaclasses‡, like, absolutely all the time (for better or for worse); and in the course of doing so I have never done any of the following things:

1. reassigned a `__class__` attribute;
2. inspected the `__class__` cell variable of anything; nor
3. messed around with this supposed `__classcell__` namespace entry, in like any capacity

… Naturally, your programming experience will be different from mine, who knows what one does. It is not that any one of those aforementioned stratagems are *de facto* problematic, necessarily. But I am no stranger to bending Python’s type systems and metaprogramming facilities to my whim, and these particular things have never presented themselves as partiuclarly useful, especially once you are working within the general context of metaclasses, and what they do.

By which I suppose I mean, tl;dr: you are on the cusp of figuring out the basics of metaclasses and what they can do – do press on and experiment, but do investigate the topic with depth as well as breath. Indeed!

---

† – In reading through code examples of this sort, you’ll often find what my snippet here calls the `attributes` dictionary referred to as `namespace` or `ns`, or similar. It’s all the same stuff.

‡ – …and ABCs and mixins and class decorators and `__init_subclass__(…)` and the abuse of `__mro_entries__(…)` for personal gain; *et cetera, ad nauseum*